# Slide right to left Android Animations

Tags: android

Hey I am working on an Android project that requires the slide animations on Android WebView.
When the user swipes from left to right it moves to the new page, and when it does that from right to left it moves to previous page. But Android has only two transitions for that namely 
slide_out_right and slide_in_left. After using them the left to right sliding work is flawless, but the other one looks weird(opposite).

Any Solutions for it. I want slide_out_left animations to be more precise.

Comment: android is open source. find the files for those animations, reversing them is not very complex.

Answer (score 152):

Have a read through this [blog post](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-animation-switching-activity.html) with an example of transition animations, I've included the code below:

### Calling Activity

```
package com.as400samplecode;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button nextActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
  nextActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.nextActivity:
   Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
   startActivity(nextActivity);
   //push from bottom to top
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
   //slide from right to left
   //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
   break;

   // More buttons go here (if any) ...

  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}
```

### Layout Resource for the Calling Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity"
 android:background="@color/ivory"> 
 <Button android:id="@+id/nextActivity" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
  android:text="Go to Next Activity" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Called Activity

```
package com.as400samplecode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NextActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

        Button previousActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousActivity);
        previousActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.previousActivity:
   finish();
   //push from top to bottom
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);
   //slide from left to right
   //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
   break;

   // More buttons go here (if any) ...

  }
 }


}
```

### Layout Resource for the Called Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".NextActivity"
 android:background="@color/khaki">

 <Button android:id="@+id/previousActivity" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
  android:text="Go to Previous Activity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Animation Resource - push_down_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="5000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - push_down_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="5000" />
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - push_up_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="5000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - push_up_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="5000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

### Animation Resource - slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Great code examples, could you explain some of the particular details of the answer with some links to good documentation/reading.

Comment: You can easily turn down the duration numbers to have some more "modern" speed animations :)

Comment: @ZooMagic how to do that? please share :)

Comment: @Darari for example android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"

Answer (score 33):

You can do Your own Animation style as an xml file like this(put it in anim folder):

left to right:

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="500"/>
  </set>
```

right to left:

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
     <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
   </set>
```

here You can set Your own values at duration, maybe it depends on the phone model how the animation will look like, try some values out if it looks not good.

and then You can call it in Your activity:

```
     Intent animActivity = new Intent(this,YourStartAfterAnimActivity.class);
      startActivity(nextActivity);

      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.your_left_to_right, R.anim.your_right_to_left);
```

Comment: This is for activity, what about slide in a textview within an activity?

Comment: if the text is too large, it gets cut !

Comment: @SiKni8  you will know about animations for textview within an activity via visiting the link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Answer (score 30):

For sliding both activity (old and new) same direction:

> **left_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     />
```

> **right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     />
```

> **left_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

> **right_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

> **startActivity transition:**

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

> **onBackPressed transition:**

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);
```

Answer (score 10):

[image: Example GIF]

The easiest way I found is using `Activity Transitions`, it is really easy

Override `onCreate` method in activity you want to run with animation:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      Slide slide = new Slide();
      slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.RIGHT);

      getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
```

Then start it using transitions (instead activity.startActivity(context)):

```
activity.startActivity(starter, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity).toBundle());
```

For closing activity with animation instead using this.finish() use below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      getActivity().finishAfterTransition();
    } else getActivity().finish();
```

For more information check below links:

- [Material-Animations with examples (recommended)](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)
- [Defining Custom Animations](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)

Answer (score 7):

See this link.. you can see so many kinds of animations here, just copy the xml to your res/anim folder and use it like the following..

```
listView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.slide_in_right));
```

[Animation Lists](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/)

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own animations. For example create xml file in res/anim like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%p"
            android:toXDelta="0"
            android:startOffset="0"
            android:duration="500"
            /> </set>
```

Then override animations in selected activity:

```
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationIN, R.anim.animationOUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Right to left new page animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="800%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="600" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="500" />
```

Comment: Works for me, although it would be better if you wrote some description on where and how to use this.

Comment: Also, for those who want to slide out left, assign fromXDelta to "0%p" and toXDelta to "-100%p"

Answer (score 0):

**First Activity**

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle())
```

**Second Activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    with(window) {
        requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
        exitTransition = Slide(Gravity.START)
        enterTransition = Slide(Gravity.END)
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        finishAfterTransition()
    }
}
```