# android activity open with swap motion

Tags: java, android

Can I open an android activity with something like a swap motion instead of the default one.
By default when I call one activity from another the new one is open from the middle and kind of grows to the match the screen size, I want the activities in my application to open from the side and cover the activity before them.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this by cutom animation, as i have done that here:

put activity_push_up_in.xml in your anim folder :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />



</set>
```

now, put another xml push_up_out.xml again in your anim folder :-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />


</set>
```

Now put this code in your java file to start activity with this animation :-

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, it is possible

In API level 5 you can call the overridePendingTransition method specify an explicit transition animation.

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.some_animation);
```

You of course will need to create the animation you wish to use in an animation xml.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use animations and override the current animation when a new Activity is started.
Take a look at this answer [Slide right to left Android Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147840/slide-right-to-left-android-animations)

Answer (score 0):

as i have done Like:

```
put activity_push_up_in.xml in your anim folder :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />



</set>
now, put another xml push_up_out.xml again in your anim folder :-

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />


</set>
Now put this code in your java file to start intent activity with this animation :-

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
```