# Repeat animated background

Tags: java, android, xml

I've made an app with an animated background, here is the code:

Main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >
...
```

The animation list:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_39" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_38" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_37" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_36" android:duration="100" />
...
```

The java implementation:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    LinearLayout bck;
    AnimationDrawable ad;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bck = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
        bck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_animation);
        ad = (AnimationDrawable) bck.getBackground();
        ad.start();
}
```

Well, it works fine as fullscreen animated background, but i would like to repeat the animated image in background.
There is a way?

Thanks, and sorry by grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your animation list xml file you can put a repeat setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:repeatCount="infinite">
```

Would that help?

or you can set

```
android:oneshot="false"
```

Edit:

If you would like to have the background slide maybe you can look at this question:

[Slide right to left Android Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147840/slide-right-to-left-android-animations)

Comment: Oh, sorry bro. I explained it wrong.
Your code is right, but i would like to repeat the background image, not the animation.

Comment: hm. ok. I'm not sure what you mean by that although I'd still like to help. btw I'm a "sis" not a "bro"