# NavigationGraph animation not working issue Android

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I am using this code with `NavigationGraph Fragment`

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/editProfileFragment"
        android:name="com.uvm.ui.editprofile.EditProfileFragment"
        android:label="FragmentFour"
        tools:layout="@layout/edit_fragment_profile" >
        <action
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            android:id="@+id/action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment"  />
    </fragment>
```

and then

```
navController.navigate(R.id.editProfileFragment);
```

using for navigation of fragment. its working fine and fragment replace as well but `enterAnim, exitAnim` etc properties not working. fragment replacing without animation. how could i resolved this?
 one more query is that is `NavigationGraph` replace fragment or add fragment? and how could i get total count of stack?

Comment: `NavigationGraph` replace fragment.

Comment: ok @Anmol animation not working when replacing fragment how could i resolved this issue?

Answer (score 28):

As i can see you are using RID of Fragment to navigate while to apply transaction animation you are giving all the animation's in the action's.

```
<action
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            android:id="@+id/action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment"  />
```

So, to apply animation's use RID of action to navigate.

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment);
```

*By default Navigation Component use Replace Fragment Transaction's.*

And  `how could i get total count of stack?`

currently i have not found a way to get this count what is your use case her can you explain?

This should work.

Comment: getting IllegalArgumentException :id/action_editProfileFragment_to_profileFragment is unknown to this NavController

Comment: That mean's your action id doesn't exist so check your nav_graph and the action id u gave for `EditProfileFragment` to `profileFragment` and use that to navigate.
@aj0822ArpitJoshi

Answer (score 0):

**implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0"**

```
Add :
 app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
 app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
 app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
 app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"

    

Anim link : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147840/slide-right-to-left-android-animations
```